# Node.js (Express): How to include correct value for 'src' attribute of an 'img' tag?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I have an image which I want to be shown as the background of the homepage. This is what I'm doing,

```
 background: url(../../imgs/b2.jpeg) no-repeat center fixed;
```

The image is located in the folder 'imgs' and the navigation is correct. Now, I'm listening on port `5000` of my local host address. `(127.0.0.1)` and when I preview my application the image is unable to load due to the following error,

> http://127.0.0.1:3000/imgs/b1.jpeg - Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is because the browser is looking for the file relative to the IP address. How do I specify the correct location in this case of my image which is saved locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: node.js does not serve ANY files by default.  You must have a route that is capable of serving any file that you expect the nodejs server to response to a request for.  `app.use("/somepath", express.static("somelocalpath"))` is often used to serve static files.  And, in your client, you should probably use root URLs like `/imgs/b2.jpeg`, not `../../`.  Remember URLs are just something handed to the server - they are not direct file system references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I eventually solved it, I set-up my app to serve the public directory,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

After that, this is how I specified the path to my images which I stored in `public/imgs` 
`localhost:3000/imgs/b1.jpeg`
And voila, it worked!